# HTACCESS 301 redirect URL with query string with no request URI

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site that has a bunch of URLs indexed in Google that look like this -

http://www.domain-namr.com/?option=filter&option2=&option3=

I am trying to redirect all of these to a new URL in HTACCESS with this code -

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^option=filter$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ /new-url.html [R=301,L]
```

Of course it is not working. On all of the pages that have a filename I can use in the request uri condition, the redirects work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working due to the wrong regex pattern in your rule.

Try this rule as your **very first rule** in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=filter(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /new-url.html? [R=301,L]
```